# Is there anything similar to microbenchmark but tells you how often code fails?

Tags: r

So I want something a bit like `microbenchmark` but instead of timing my code, I want to know how often it fails (if at all). Essentially, I want to test something like

```
f1 <- function(x){
  x^2 - 1
}

lims <- rnorm(2)

try(uniroot(f1, lims))
```

a large number of times (say, 10^6 tests), and then record the frequency at which it fails. Of course, in this simple example it just boils down to having exactly one of 1 or -1  in `lims`. In general I won't know this.

I need to solve a polynomial as part of a shiny app. I want to keep the app as clean as possible so want to avoid the user specifying the `uniroot` limits. I've therefore written an adaptive method, a few simulations suggests it works, but I want to test it a large number of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably just as easy to write your own function to do this. Perhaps something like:

```r
count_failures <- function(f, n = 1e3, ...)
{
  n_failures <- 0
  for(i in seq(n))
  {
    tryCatch(f(...), error = function(e) n_failures <<- n_failures + 1)
  }
  cat("Function \"", deparse(substitute(f)), "\" failed on ", n_failures,
      " out of ", n, " runs. (", 100*n_failures/n, "%)\n", sep = "")
}
```

Now we'll see how it works with your set-up:

```
f1 <- function(x){
  x^2 - 1
}

f2 <- function()
{
  lims <- rnorm(2)
  uniroot(f1, lims)
}

count_failures(f2)
#> Function "f2" failed on 552 out of 1000 runs. (55.2%)

count_failures(f2, 1e5)
#> Function "f2" failed on 56702 out of 1e+05 runs. (56.702%)
```